# Android: Checkbox absent if background present

Tags: android, api, checkbox, background, visible

I'm making an Activity with a ListView. Each row is made of two TextView and one CheckBox. The problem is that if I add the background attribute to the checkbox, it doesn't show in the row (not because it's transparent).
Does anybody have an explanation?

Actually it works fine either way on API 19, but the tests are made on the emulator with API 11 and I want to target API 8+.

Thank you in advance.

Image without the background attribute.

Image with the background attribute (You can see the strings going till the end of the frame):

[can't load images because of my reputation...]

The code is following.

Thank You in advance.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListaMyLocationSalvate);

    ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    array.add(new String[]{"asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd","asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"});
    array.add(new String[]{"asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd","asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"});

    Adapter arAdapter = new Adapter(this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(arAdapter);
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]>{

Activity context;
ArrayList<String[]> array;

public Adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String[]> array) {
    super(activity, R.layout.row, array);
    this.context = activity;
    this.array = array;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) {
        view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRow1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRow2);
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
    tv1.setText(((String[])(array.get(position)))[0]);
    tv2.setText(((String[])(array.get(position)))[1]);
    cb.setChecked(false);

    return view;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvListaMyLocationSalvate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml (CheckBox background attribute makes the difference)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#000000"        
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cb"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvRow1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default background for the CheckBox is @android:drawable/btn_check_label_background.  If you look at the drawable in your \platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable-hdpi folder, you'll find a nine-patch image that effectively defines the minimum height and width of your CheckBox and adds some left padding for the text such that the check box part of your CheckBox doesn't run into the text.  By changing the background to a color (and not defining any text) there's no minimum height or width anymore, effectively hiding your CheckBox.

If you want a black background, you'll want to copy the btn_check_label_background image over to your res\drawable-hdpi folder, and modify it so that the bits you want black are black. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch for more details about how nine-patch drawables work.